# Why aren't mp3 files I deleted by accident showing up in the Trash?

Tags: trash, macos

I accidentally deleted all the mp3 files on my computer (as opposed to just the ones in my downloads folder). There were a lot of files (around 2,000) so it took a while to delete but now, although at the bottom trash says it holds 2,500 files, they don't show up.

I need to drag these back onto my computer into their respective folders but I can't find them.

I am running Mac OS X 10.8 (Leopard) on an iMac.

Any assistance would be much appreciated!

Comment: How did you delete them? Did you drag them to the trash? Did you press Cmd+Backspace? In which application did you delete them (Finder? iTunes? or something else?).

Comment: They were deleted in the Finder by being dragged into trash. I thought I had searched for all of the mp3s in my downloads folder but the search was my whole computer.

Comment: If you drag into trash from the Finder - if you realise immediately then edit->undo will get them back - (and you can do several undos)

Comment: How are you sure they are not in the trash?

Comment: @Mark - I'm afraid it's too late now. Finder says it can't undo.

Comment: @GEdgar - they ARE in trash (as shown by the iTunes file path and the number of files trash says it holds: I emptied it then deleted 500 files and 2,000 mp3s and it says I have 2,500 files in there). What I need to do is make them visible so I can manually drag and drop them back to their folders.

Comment: Try the following: open the application Terminal (it's in the Utilities folder) and type: 'ls -a ~/.Trash' (without quotes). Do you see all the files that you're expecting in the output?

Comment: Yes I do, is there a command to move them to another folder? In the short term I don't mind where they are, as long as they're not sitting in the trash waiting to get deleted!

Comment: Added my answer below to have enough room for formatting. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

> Yes I do, is there a command to move them to another folder? In the short term I don't mind where they are, as long as they're not sitting in the trash waiting to get deleted!

Answering down here to have enough room.

1. Create a new folder to move all these files from the Trash into. It can be anything, for this example I'll create a folder called "undeleted" on the Desktop.
2. Open up a Terminal window, and navigate to the Trash: `cd ~/.Trash`.
3. Confirm that the stuff you want is there: `ls -a`.
4. Move the mp3s:

   ```
   mv *.mp3 ~/Desktop/undeleted
   ```

   . If you create a different folder somewhere else, the easiest way to get its path is to drag it into the Terminal window. Type in

   ```
   mv *.mp3
   ```

   including the trailing space, then drag the folder you want the files to go into into the window - it'll automatically fill in the correct path. The * wildcard will match any .mp3 it finds.
5. If you have any AAC encoded songs, repeat the above, but change the extension to .m4a:

   ```
   mv *.m4a ~/Desktop/undeleted
   ```